# delete rows from databse using a shell script

Tags: oracle, scripting, sqlplus

the below script gives me an error. Basically I am trying to delete the records that I got from the first query. I have put them in a text file, formatted them and used them in the delete operation.

**After executing the script I am getting the below error:-
: line 5: syntax error at line 27: `<<' unmatched**

Comment: sqlplus -s $dbcreds << EOF > output.txt
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
select empname from emp where dept_no=123;
EOF
if [ -s "output.txt" ]
then
        echo " Found the below employees....Deleting them from Database ..............!!!! \n"
        cat output.txt
        sed "s/\(.*\)/'\1'/" output.txt| tr '\n' ','|sed 's/.$//' >final_employees.txt
        while read line
        do
        sqlplus -s $dbcreds <<EOF
        SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
        Delete from emp where empname in ($line);
        EOF
        done<final_employees.txt
        
else
        echo " No employees found....!!!"
fi

Comment: Please add that code into the question, formatted properly - especially as the indentation is probably crucial to your issue. This is nothing to do with Oracle really; but why do it in two steps, why not query and delete in one go, with the output of both (if you have feedback on) going to the text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't tell because the code you dumped is unformatted, but my first guess would be you have leading spaces in front of the EOF in your [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

This should work (note that there are no leading spaces in front of the EOF.:

```
sqlplus -s $dbcreds << EOF > output.txt
  SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
    select empname from emp where dept_no=123;
EOF


if [ -s "output.txt" ]
then
  echo " Found the below employees....Deleting them from Database ..............!!!! \n"
  cat output.txt
  sed "s/(.*)/'\1'/" output.txt| tr '\n' ','|sed 's/.$//' >final_employees.txt

  while read line
  do
     sqlplus -s $dbcreds <<EOF
       SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
       Delete from emp where empname in ($line);
EOF
  done  < final_employees.txt

else

  echo " No employees found....!!!"
fi
```

Comment: It displays employees from the first select query but the values are not being passed to the delete statement in the below:-

Comment: Delete from emp where empname in ($line);
 is not able to take the arguments from thefinal_employees.txt file